# Как добавить кнопку "закрыть" в DialogBox?

Tags: gwt, java

Я хочу добавить к моему диалоговому окну (DialogBox) в правый верхний угол (рядом с заголовком) кнопку "закрыть". Но если добавлять handler никакие события не приходят. Стандартный обходной путь - sinkEvents + обработка в onBrowserEvents не помогает (не приходят события). Как обойти этот баг?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `onBrowserEvents` события приходить не будут, потому что их блокировка захардкожена в `DialogBox`. Есть множество извращенных способов решения этой проблемы: начиная от написания своего `Caption` (что небезопасно, если верить google) до использования тяжеловесных gwt-ext или smart-gwt. На мой взгляд лучшим решением может служить следующий workaround:

1. Чтобы понять, каким образом блокируются события, обратим внимание на методы: `startDragging`, `continueDragging`, `endDragging` класса `DialogBox`, т.е. блокировка сделана для реализации `dnd`.
2. Переопределим метод `startDragging`, добавив в него поиск по элементам заголовка (рекурсивно от последнего к первому).

Простейший пример диалогового окна с возможностью закрытия:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.EventTarget;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.MouseDownEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;

public class Test extends DialogBox {
  private Image myCloseImage = new Image("close.png");

  public Test() {
    HorizontalPanel headPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    headPanel.add(myCloseImage);
    headPanel.add(new Label("Title"));
    headPanel.setCellHorizontalAlignment(myCloseImage, HorizontalPanel.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    headPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");
    setHTML(headPanel + "");
    setWidget(new Label("Dialog content..."));
  }

  private Element findCloseButton(Element caption) {
    for (int i = caption.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      Element childElement = (Element) caption.getChild(i);

      // идентифицировать кнопку закрытия можно более продуманным способом
      // здесь просто проверяется, является ли элемент картинкой (image)
      // т.е. ищем крайнюю справа картинку
      if (childElement.toString().equals(myCloseImage.getElement().toString())) {
        return childElement;
      }
      Element result = findCloseButton(childElement);
      if (result != null) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void beginDragging(MouseDownEvent event) {
    super.beginDragging(event);
    EventTarget et = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
    Element te = (Element) com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element.as(et);
    Element caption = ((HTML) getCaption()).getElement();
    Element closeButton = findCloseButton(caption);
    if (closeButton.isOrHasChild(te)) {
      hide();
    }
  }
}
```